# How to find the columns used in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to get a list of used columns in a particular procedure using PL/SQL? I have to check over 500 procedures in my Oracle DB and print out all the columns used in them.

Comment: What if another procedure fetches some columns from the query into local variables and then passes these variables to your procedure ? What if some query calculates an expressiion like `column1+column2*column3 As new_alias` and then this alias is passed to your procedure ?

Comment: What a strange task you've got. Suppose you have a procedure that opens a sys_refcursor like this   `select * from some_table`, and then reads into a record, where fields named differently. What columns are considered used in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, Oracle does make the calculated *table* dependencies in PL/SQL available for viewing:

```
select * from user_dependencies -- can also use all_ or dba_dependencies
where type = 'PROCEDURE' and REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

But if you really need column-level dependencies, I think it'll be much more difficult. Here's a very simple answer that'll illustrate some of the problems with the question.

```
select name, type, line, text, table_name, column_name 
from user_source
join user_tab_cols
  on text like '%'|| column_name || '%';
```

So you can search through all your procedures for any strings that match an existing column name. I can think of dozens of problems with this approach; the commenters above mentioned some of them, like how deep into the call stack you want to look. Or depending on how your columns are named, ambiguous names (SID, MODIFIED_DATE, etc) will produce duplicate entries. And there's no way to distinguish between actual references to column names and local variables which happen to have the same spelling. Or comments. And views or synonyms can screw up your searching. It seems like a really tough question. I hope the tables from *user_dependencies* will be enough for your needs.